# OpenMP - Hanging during execution

Tags: c++, gdb, openmp

I'm experiencing an inconsistent behavior of a program that's parallelized using OpenMP.

When I run it, it prints out its current stage, so the expected output is: "2 3 4 5" etc.
Time between the first few stages is usually 1 to 2 seconds (when running in parallel on 4 cores).

However, without recompiling, or altering anything, sometimes when I run the software it hangs  right after printing `2` (which is printed before the first parallel code is executed);

It doesn't become slow, it literally stops computing. I've run this under gdb and confirmed that it hangs inside of OpenMP:

(there are more than 4 threads because of hyperthreading)

```
[New Thread 0x7ffff6c78700 (LWP 25878)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff6477700 (LWP 25879)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5c76700 (LWP 25880)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff5475700 (LWP 25881)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff4c74700 (LWP 25882)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff4473700 (LWP 25883)]
[New Thread 0x7ffff3c72700 (LWP 25884)]
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0x00007ffff7641fd4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffff7640a9e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgomp.so.1
(gdb) 
#2  0x0000000000408ae8 in Redcraft::createStructures (this=0x7fffffffd8d0) at source/redcraft.cpp:512
512 #pragma omp parallel for private(node)
```

Originally the `pragma` specified `schedule(dynamic)` but having that or removing that doesn't change the consistency of this hangup.
Lastly, I tried enabling/disabling `omp_set_dynamic()` and that had no effect either.

Any suggestions for debugging?

Comment: This is almost certainly (?) a symptom of a data-race, but it's kind of difficult to diagnose properly without seeing the patient, I mean, without seeing the code.

Comment: Code is open-source, but rather large. What would you need to see?

Comment: As far as I understood, data-race would either cause wrong answer, or infinite loop in *my* code. But when I abort the process using gdb, it's not inside of my loop, it's inside the #pragma statement.

What's more -- when it doesn't hang, the results are identical.

Comment: Try running with Thread Analyzer from Oracle Solaris Studio (despite the name there is a free Linux version). It detects lots of threading issues.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when there is data race.You'll have to post the code block that is being parallelized.Basically what is to be found out is how the threads are using the data.Rerunning without compiling doesn't guarantee the same thread execution sequence hence these kind of problems arise.Are you working with files?You'll have to close them before rerunning.

Comment: What kind of data race would for the program to hang?